# Trying to make a Workbook Save after 5 Loops

Tags: excel, vba

I inserted this For loop right before the end of another loop in order to save the workbook after every 5 iterations of the original for loop.

```
'Saves Workbook after 5 Calculation
           
    For k = 2 To RowCount Step 5                
        If k = i Then ThisWorkbook.Save
    Next k
Next i
```

It is saying that there is no next for the 'for k loop'

How can I fix this and is there a better way?

Comment: You could just use `Mod` here and ditch the `For k` loop completely.

Comment: how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a double loop there, where the save command will be running several times inside the original loop.

To save every 5 iterations of the loop, you would need to add something simpler.  Try with:

```
     If (i-1) Mod 5 = 0  Then ThisWorkbook.Save
Next i
```

What this code does is it will run every time the remainder of the `i` counter is divisible by 5, thus saving every 5 iterations of your counter.